# Class for Doubly-Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

I have to code a class for handling a Doubly-Linked List that doesn't have an empty head or tail node. I have modified some code I obtained that is supposed to be for a Doubly-Linked List but it is throwing the following exception. How do I prevent the exception occurring and what changes are required to remove the empty head or tail node?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at P4DLL.removeLast(P4DLL.java:105)
    at P4DLL.main(P4DLL.java:197)
```

Code:

```
class ListNode
{
    Object element;
    ListNode next;
    ListNode prev;

    public ListNode( Object anElement )
    {
        element = anElement;
        next = null;
        prev = null;
    }

    public ListNode( Object anElement,  ListNode nextPtr, ListNode prevPtr)
    {
        element = anElement;
        next = nextPtr;
        prev = prevPtr;
    }
} // end class ListNode

public class P4DLL
{

    private ListNode head;
    private ListNode tail;
    private int size;

    public P4DLL()
    {
        head = null;
        tail = null;
        size = 0;
    }

    public void addAtFirst( Object anElement )
    {
        //create a new node to be stored at the beginning of the list
        ListNode newNode = new ListNode( anElement);
        newNode.next = head;
        head = newNode;
        size++;

        if(tail == null)
            tail = head;
    }

    public void addAtLast( Object anElement )
    {
        //create a new node to be stored at the begginning of the list
        ListNode newNode = new ListNode( anElement);

        if(tail == null)
        {
            head = tail = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            tail.next = newNode;
            tail = tail.next;
        }

        size++;
    }

    public Object removeFirst( )
    {
        //the list has no elements to remove
        if ( isEmpty( ) )
        {
            return null;
        }

        //get a ptr to the first data node
        ListNode ptr = head.next;

        //save the data in this node so it can be returned
        Object data = head.next.element;

        //link around this node
        ptr.next.prev = ptr.prev;
        ptr.prev.next = ptr.next;

        size--;

        //return the data in this node
        return data;
    }

    public Object removeLast( )
    {
        //if the list has no elements there is nothing to return
        if ( isEmpty( ) )
        {
            return null;
        }

        //get a ptr to the last data node
        ListNode ptr = tail.prev;

        //save the data in this node so it can be returned
        Object data = tail.element;

        //link around this node
        ptr.next.prev = ptr.prev; // P4DLL.java:105
        ptr.prev.next = ptr.next;

        size--;

        //return the data in this node
        return data;
    }

    public Object getFirstElement( )
    {
        if ( size == 0 )
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return head.next.element;
        }
    }

    public Object getLastElement( )
    {
        if ( size == 0 )
            return null;
        else
            return tail.prev.element;
    }

    public int getNumElements( )
    {
        return size;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty( )
    {
        return size == 0;
    }

    public void displayList( )
    {
        if ( isEmpty( ) )
        {
            System.out.println ( "The list is empty.\n" );
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println ( this.toString( ) );
        }
    }   

    public String toString( )
    {
        String returnStr = "";

        if ( ! isEmpty( ) )
        {
            ListNode ptr = head.next;

            while ( ptr != tail )
            {
                returnStr += ptr.element.toString ();
                returnStr += "\n";
                ptr = ptr.next;
            }
        }

        return returnStr;
    }

 // makes the list empty
 public void clear( )
 {
     if ( ! isEmpty( ) )
     {
         head.next = tail;
         tail.prev = head;
         size = 0;
     }
 }

  public static void main ( String[] args )
  {
        P4DLL list = new P4DLL( );
        list.addAtFirst ( "Abe" );
        list.addAtFirst ( "Beth");
        list.addAtLast ( "Ed" );
        list.displayList ();
        System.out.println( "The number of elements in this list is "
                            + list.getNumElements() );

        System.out.println( "\nNow remove the last element and display.\n" );
        list.removeLast(); // P4DLL.java:197
        list.displayList ();
  }

}
```

Comment: You'd do better to post a specific question about your code. (And please fix the formatting, so it is easier to read: simply indent your entire program four spaces.)

Comment: Choose Tools | Templates and open the template in the editor.

Comment: is the format right now? Sorry I'm new here.

Comment: "No idea to continue" -> Translation: No motivation to work it out yourself.
Sorry, I have been disillusioned as a student tutor for some time now.

Comment: Running @toc's code causes an exception to occur.  I've added the comment to the end of the question and commented the referenced lines in the code.

Comment: Also, in the future make your question more detailed please. How do i continue from here is kind of .... non descript.

Comment: I'm confused. You're writing this in Java but you need to test it as a DLL? That makes no sense.

Comment: I was confused for a second too, @Dan.  DLL = Doubly-Linked List

Comment: Don't be lazy and expect us to do your homework.

Answer (score 5):

You code is producing a `NullPointerException` inside the `removeLast()` method. Fix it! :-D

It seems you copied this code from somewhere, including the spelling mistakes:
 http://www.cramster.com/answers-jul-09/computer-science/doubly-linked-list-xi5te-program-implements-class-doubly-linked_619688.aspx

The code is currently written assuming head and tail nodes.  You'll need to re-write this method (and likely others) to account for this new reality.

**Edit:**

I just finished reviewing the diff between your code and the code I found in the above link.  My suggestion is to completely scrap it and write the linked list from scratch.  Not only was it written assuming head and tail nodes, **it's also broken** in at least one way.  You've noticed this yourself since `size--` was missing from the supplied `removeLast()` and you had to add it yourself. There's also the issue of the comments talking about "pointers", and the spelling mistakes, and etc.

Here's a starting point.  This is a working implementation of `removeLast()`:

```
public Object removeLast( ) {
    if (size == 0) return null;
    final Object result = last.element;
    if (size == 1)
        first = last = null;
    else {
        last = last.prev;
        last.next = null;
    }
    size--;
    return result;
}
```

Since you're not using head or tail nodes, I'm using fields called `first` and `last` for better clarity.

Comment: +1 for finding that the code had been copied :)

Comment: Ahh I agree, nice catch.  Though I think it would have been a good thing if he'd stayed with that and was caught by MOSS or something.

Comment: I got the code from my professor and I edited some of the methods myself, I don't even know there was another copy of code in other website. For the one who said I did not try to work it myself, I read the whole chapter on list and even search online for hours before I decided asking for help here.